# MySQL is not logging queries into log file

Tags: mysql-5.5

I am using MySQL 5.5 with Amazon Linux 2013. Following is my configuration for log file.

```
slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time=0
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.log
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysqld_slow_query.log
general-log = 'ON'
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysqld_normal.log
log = /var/log/mysqld_normal.log
```

But, It is not logging the queries in log file. particularly I have to find the queries which is not using Index at all.

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**For logging slow queries** do like below, It will log all queries those are not using indexes as well as which are taking more than 1 sec

```
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/log/mysqld_slow_query.log
long_query_time                = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

**For Error log**

```
log-error                      = /var/log/mysqld.log
```

**For general log**

```
general_log_file               = /var/log/mysqld_normal.log
general_log                    = 1
```

Comment: I did the same, but I did get any queries in log.

Comment: In Slow log or in any of the log ? Does the files are created ?

Comment: I have configured as above and log files are created. but, not working.

Comment: There is nothing in `/var/log/mysqld_slow_query.log` ?

Comment: Yes, nothing in slow query log file.